# Как заполнить progressBar на всю высоту?

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

Как можно заставить обычный progressBar заполниться по всей высоте?

Потому что когда я задаю высоту, то у самой полоски она не меняется:

[image]

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас насколько я вижу из скриншота виджет имеет ширину родителя. Оранжевая полоска это прогресс вероятнее всего, и он устанавливается так:

```
android:max="100"  
android:progress="100"<--- прогресс 100/100
```

либо программно:

```
probressbar.setMax(100);
probressbar.setProgress(100);
```

[вот туториал](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/progressbar.php) по работе с данным виджетом.

Comment: Немного не то, что нужно)) Но за ссылку на туториал спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что это за "обычный" `ProgressBar`. Но я думаю, что никак.

Каждая `View` должна наследоваться от класса View. В этом классе есть метод `onMeasure()` который отвечает за то как будет измерена и `View`. При написании любой `View` в этом методе описывается логика как должна изменяться `View` в зависимости от того какие размеры на экране ей заданы. Я подозреваю, что конкретно в этой View высота ее "относительно" фиксированна.

Но вы можете написать свой кастомный ProgressBar и задать ему любые размеры, хотя задача это не самая простая для понимания. [Вот](https://tuhub.ru/posts/realizatsiya-custom-view-komponenta-v-android) неплохая статья на тему кастомных `View`.